# TextArea in Table Cell strange issue

Tags: java-me, textarea, lwuit

I have worked with javame + lwuit.

I encountered an unusual behavior of textarea, when it is inside table cell. Originally textarea ыhifted to right over edge of cell, then I set a fixed size, the problem goes away, but there was another - even though that textarea was stretched to full screen, the text is drawn according to old boundaries.

This looks like:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ This text would                                        +
+ fit, but somehow                                      +
+ transferred to                                           +
+ another line                                              +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Please help if you are faced with similar problems or know what it was.

Comment: @Maxim When you think your problem has been resolved by an answer click the "check" mark at the left side of that answer to make people know that it was the right solution of the problem !

Comment: do you use `setpreferredXXXX` to set size?

Comment: yes, i use setPrefferedW

Comment: TextArea has the `column` attribute which is the maximum number of characters to display in a row. So take a look at this !

Comment: Thanks :) Problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Cells in a table take up their preferred width or the cell constraint percentage if one is defined.

Preferred width for a text field/text area is calculated based on the columns value for the text area/text field. E.g. to increase the preferred width of a text area just increase the columns by deriving Table and overriding createCell like this:

```
protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
    Component c = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
    if(c instanceof TextArea) {
         ((TextArea)c).setColumns(50);
    }
    return c;
}
```